# Что это строка означает?

Tags: php

Можете подсказать, что делает пятая строка:

```
$getResponse = getResponse($data, 200, 'application/json');
```

Код целиком

```
<?php
    require_once 'Request.php';
    require_once 'Response.php';
    $data = "mgoni gagebuli davaleba";
    $getResponse = getResponse($data, 200, 'application/json');
    echo $getResponse;
```

Comment: Какая из строк четвёртая? Здесь нет нумерации. Какой фреймворк/CMS используете?

Comment: $getResponse = getResponse($data, 200, 'application/json'); вот это

Comment: В переменную $getResponse записывается результат вызова функции getResponse(). Без знания фреймворка больше сказать тут сложно.

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис, смею предположить это некое подобие rest api для вывода данных в формате json, `200` это код ошибки/успеха, а `application/json` формат json для вывода.